# Inventory management python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to subtract current stock when releasing
I'm new to python I hope someone helps me with this problem

```
def Release_Materials():
print("==================")
print("Release Materials")
print("==================")
for item in inventory:
    item_index = int(input("what is the index of the item you would like to change? (type 0 to cancel): ")) - 1
    if item_index == "0":
        return
    if item_index < 0:
        return
    if check_valid_index(item_index) == False:
        print("")
        print("Error: The Index Does not exist! ")
        return
    else:
        break
    quantity = int(input("what is the quantity of item you would like to change? (type 0 to cancel): "))
    if quantity == "0":
        return
    if quantity < 0:
        return
    print(f"{inventory[item_index].get_name()} - OLD QUANTITY: {inventory[item_index].get_stock()}")
    inventory[item_index].update_stock(quantity)
    print(f"{inventory[item_index].get_name()} - NEW QUANTITY: {inventory[item_index].get_stock()}")
    print("Quantity Successfully Updated! ")
else:
    print("No items added yet! ")

MenuDisplay()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgi8k.jpg)
Here is my full code
https://pastebin.pl/view/d4441a68

Comment: Please see [ask]. Include a [mre] of your code here (not full code, and not on an external website), as [_formatted text_](/help/formatting), not screenshots. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Please be sure to indent your code correctly. It is not enough to just indent your _first_ line of code. You need to either indent _all lines_ (code blocks) or add lines containing only three backticks (`\`\`\``) before and after your code (code fences) (See [formatting help](/help/formatting))

Comment: Please also read the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and include what your code does, what you expected it to do, and an actual specific question as a part of your question

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).